# iOS 8 Europe/Moscow Time Zone Issue

Tags: ios, nsdate, ios8, nsdateformatter

This strange issue appeared with ios 8 release. Here is  sample code:

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1414785600];

dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru_RU"]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Moscow"]];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSString * month = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
```

Date is `2014-11-01 00:00:00 MSK` (or `2014-10-31 20:00:00 +0000`)

Running ios 7, month value is 11. But on ios 8 it is 10.
Any ideas what's wrong?
Thanks.

PS. Checking Asia/Muscat timezone right now (+4 like MSK). Everything is OK, month is 11.

Comment: Did you check if the value is the same in different timezones?

Answer (score 3):

`[timezone secondsFromGMTForDate:date]` returns 14400 at iOs7 and 10800 at iOs8 for the given date. It should reflect the changes done (again) by the russian government http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/russia/moscow which iOs7 isn't aware of yet.

Comment: So it's an iOS 7 issue, and not an iOS 8 issue?

Comment: I believe so, usually the old iOs versions receive minor updates for such changes.